The EVM executes a part of the bytecode instruction
Recently, I have been working on inserting a function call into an existing smart contract function at the assembly level. I successfully inserted the function call (b) into an existing function (a), and then called function (a). However, while function (a) is called, my inserted function (b) is not called. Using EVM-Trace for debugging, I found that it enters function (a) but stops at a specific point before the call to function (b) is made, regardless of my modifications. There are no errors or warnings. I have confirmed that both the deployed contract and the function call have sufficient gas, but I can't figure out the issue.
I hope someone can help me with this.
Here is part of the code I inserted:
1915: PUSH1 0x00
1917: DUP1
1918: PUSH1 0x44
1920: DUP4
1921: PUSH1 0x00
1923: PUSH20 0x2fd82b67cba721f941e784c67aeb0f938aede2c8
1944: PUSH2 0xc350
1947: CALL

it stops at pc 1923.
